# icon of uploaded file in gridview when file has saved in database

Tags: asp.net, linq

before i have a question about (icon of uploaded file in gridview) and recieved below code.

this code seems that is for when we save files in the server.
now if we save files in database how i have to change the code.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

public string GetIconFromFile()
{
Icon ic = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Server.MapPath (".")+"/Files/Test.txt");
string imagePath=Server.MapPath(".") + "/Images/Test.ico";
if (ic != null)
{
   using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
       ic.Save(stream);
    }
}
    return imagePath ;

}

protected void GridViewEfile_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    img = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");
    img.ImageUrl = GetIconFromFile();
}
}
```

.aspx

```
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileID")%>'><%#Eval("FileName")%></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the code for upload button when i want to save in the database is like below please help what change in function (GetIconFromFile()) , special when we need filename.ico

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array

    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    string contenttype = String.Empty;



    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension

    switch (ext)
    {

        case ".doc":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".docx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".xls":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".xlsx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".jpg":

            contenttype = "image/jpg";

            break;

        case ".png":

            contenttype = "image/png";

            break;

        case ".gif":

            contenttype = "image/gif";

            break;

        case ".pdf":

            contenttype = "application/pdf";

            break;

    }

    if (contenttype != String.Empty)
    {



        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        //insert the file into database
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change function **GetIconFromFile** where you have to write code for

1. Saving icon file in the database.

   For saving image refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database)
2. Display the image from database into gridview

   For Displaying in gridview refer [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/308387-How-Display-Image-Gridview-From-database-without-using-Handler-file.aspx)

Comment: the code for upload button when i want to save in the database has been addes please help what change in function (GetIconFromFile()) , special when we need filename.ico